# Are there any strong or well established commutative encryption algorithms?

Tags: encryption, commutative-encryption

I am looking for an encryption algorithm that's secure and commutative. This means that if N parties encrypt their data in any order, it could be decrypted in any other order.

Comment: There's always $E_k(x) = x^k \bmod p$ for a publicly known prime $p$ and $k$ relatively prime to $p-1$